# Move Cloud Storage file to different bucket with Java API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How can I move a file from one bucket to another with the Cloud Storage Java API? I can find examples of [file creation](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) but not copying or deletion - and I imagine I'd have to copy the file and delete it in order to execute a move from one bucket to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Do the copy and then delete the original  after. There are some examples [on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/5cbbbae1ac80aecfa742972097c705eb8871930c/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/snippets/BlobSnippets.java#L140). Here's the gist of it:

```
 CopyWriter copyWriter = originalBlob.copyTo(BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName));
 Blob copiedBlob = copyWriter.getResult();
```